# Error when installing packages with RStudio

Tags: r, compilation

I'm having this message in RStudio when trying to install `shotext` package:
Any idea?

Many thanks in advance.

```
checking for gcc... x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/private/var/folders/rq/352qnr0x1j36tvv3ypx_bgc80000gn/T/RtmpzCR5SP/R.INSTALL19d23f947e8a/sysfonts':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Comment: Reinstall Xcode?

Comment: Already done, the problem persists. Thanks